# How to consolidate the data if there are same multiple items in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular, I want merge items which are having same names
from an array.

```
$scope.items_list = [{name: 'cars',quantity: 2}, {name: 'cars', quantity: 4},    {name: 'cars', quantity: 5},{name: 'trucks',quantity: 2}, {name: 'trucks', quantity: 3}];
```

so I want to merge the above objects into one single object where the
names are equals, and that quantity will be counted of both objects.

```
so I want the output like

$scope.items_list_merged = [{name:'cars', quantity: 11(example from above list: 2+4+5)},{name:'trucks', quantity: 5(example from above list: 2+3)}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example without lodash:

```
// Create temporary container for easy access by name
var objs = {};
angular.forEach($scope.items_list, function(item) {
    // Add new item / add to existing item's quantity
    objs[item.name] = objs[item.name] || { name: item.name, quantity: 0 };
    objs[item.name].quantity = objs[item.name].quantity + item.quantity;
})
// Push each value to an array
$scope.items_list_merged = [];
angular.forEach(objs, function(item) {
    $scope.items_list_merged.push(item);
})
```

Example with lodash:

```
$scope.items_list_merged = _.reduce($scope.items_list, function(collector, item) {
    var idx = _.findIndex(collector, {name: item.name});
    if (idx === -1) { collector.push(item) }
    else { collector[idx].quantity = collector[idx].quantity + item.quantity }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Angular, is pure Javascript and very fun too. In the following, Angular will help us only by providing its `copy()` function:

```
function aggregateByName(list) {
    // map by name, aggregating quantities
    var mappedList = list.reduce(function(aggregate, item) {
        var existingItem = aggregate[item.name];
        if( !existingItem ) {
            // copy, so as not to modify the original object
            aggregate[item.name] = angular.copy(item);
        }
        else {
            existingItem.quantity += item.quantity;
        }
        return aggregate;
    }, {});

    // convert to array of values
    return Object.keys(mappedList).map(function(key) {
        return mappedList[key];
    });
}
```

If in ES >= 6:

```
function aggregateByName(list) {
    var mappedList = list.reduce((aggregate, item) => {
        var existingItem = aggregate[item.name];
        if( !existingItem ) {
            aggregate[item.name] = angular.copy(item);
        }
        else {
            existingItem.quantity += item.quantity;
        }
        return aggregate;
    }, {});

    return Object.keys(mappedList).map(key => mappedList[key]);
}
```

Finally:

```
$scope.items_list_merged = aggregateByName($scope.items_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

first add library loadash to project then use code below :

```
var array = [];
    $scope.items_list = _.groupBy($scope.items_list, 'name');

    angular.forEach($scope.items_list , function(value , key){
         var count = 0;
        angular.forEach(value , function(list){
            count = list.quantity + count;
         });
        array.push({name:key , quantity:count}) 
    }); 
$scope.items_list = array;
```

Good Luck